# Can someone explain this block of code please

Tags: vb.net, function, class, object

```vb
Public Class CP_TYF3_1_EmployeeDetails
    Public Property EmployeeNumber As String
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Surname As String
    Public Property SalaryScale As Integer
    
    Public Function GetSalaryRange() As String
        Dim range As String = ""
        Select Case SalaryScale
            Case 1
                range = "R2500-R3000"
            Case 2
                range = "R3001-R4000"
            Case 3
                range = "R4001-R6000"
            Case 4
                range = "R6001-R9000"
            Case 5
                range = "R9001-R15000"
            Case Else
                range = "Invalid salary scale"
        End Select
        Return range
    End Function
End Class
```

I was trying to display scale range of  the employees in the listbox by trying to input it the number from 1 to 5 and expect the function to display the range scale of the salary scale.

```
°The question was that I must create a vb.net application and name it employeeDetails, then add a new class to the project and name it Employee.vb, the employee class must have the following attributes :Employee number (string), Name, Surname and salary Scale (Integer value between 1 and 5
°code the property procedures for                                   each attributes 
° Add a default constructor that sets the fields to an empty string /zero value 
°Overload the default constructor to create a copy /paramatised constructor that accepts the input for all the attributes and initialises the fields with value passed in 
° the last function its the one I'm struggling to figure it out according to the scale ranges and salary range, the one I just I shared the code up there
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow You haven't shown how this method is connected to anything else. You've said what it's meant to do, but you haven't told us what actually happens - what's the question here?

Comment: Further to the comment above, a good question needs to explain what you're trying to achieve, how you're trying to achieve it, what happens when you try and how that differs from your expectations. You've partially done the first two but the last two not at all.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear, I just edited everything you need to help please check again, hope you will help

Comment: It's not clear why you need someone to explain code that you wrote. You wrote it. You are the best qualified to explain what it does.

Comment: You haven't done the step where you do a default constructor.  You can find more info on constructors in the MSDN VB docs under Visual Basic / Object-oriented programming (Visual Basic).

Comment: (Strictly speaking, it's pointless to write a default ctor that initializes numeric variables to a value of zero, because that happens automatically anyway, but the string part isn't pointless as strings will by default initialize to a null object instead of an empty string.  Even then, I'd rather put the initialization with the declaration instead of writing a ctor to do it.  But since this is a homework assignment, you should do as the assignment says to do.)

Answer (score 0):

This code block is a simple class with some properties and a function. you can use it as

```
'create emp object from class model
        Dim emp As New CP_TYF3_1_EmployeeDetails

        'fill emp property
        emp.EmployeeNumber = 1492
        emp.Name = "vladimr"
        emp.Surname = "batman"
        emp.SalaryScale = 3

        'use class function
        Dim rng As String = emp.GetSalaryRange
        'rng return value is "R4001-R6000"
```

A class is used to create new objects from an empty model. Each object is a copy of the class with defined properties. In the example above, we have defined a new unique "emp" object that can be used further.